# Intersect two List<> in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have two `List<T>` objects that I would like to intersect, but I get errors when trying.

```
// Make the Keys in the Dictionary<Load, double> _loads to form a List<Load>
List<Load> l1 = _loads.Keys.ToList();

// Get a list from my element.
List<Load> l2 = element.ListLoads;

// Intersect
List<Load> loads = (List<Load>)l1.Intersect<Load>(l2);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Intersect<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) returns an [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx), so the correct way is:

```
var loads = l1.Intersect(l2).ToList();
```

[`ToList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) creates a `List<T>` from an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Note that you can omit the type argument when invoking `Intersect<T>`, the compiler is smart enough to infer it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
List<Load> loads=new List<Load>(l1.Intersect(l2));
```

This is because Intersect will return an IEnumerable and this is the right way to create a new list from an IEnumerable.